# How to store face properties for a CGAL Nef_Polyhedra for convex decomposition

Tags: mesh, cgal, csg

I need to use the CGAL [convex decomposition algorithm](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/index.html) but it seems to only work for a `Nef_Polyhedra` object. Also, my 3D mesh needs to have face properties (like those provided by the `Surface_mesh` object, see [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html#title7)). And I'd like to keep the face properties while performing the convex decomposition.

The face properties are defining a texture UV mapping, each face can have a different texture.

Is there a way to assign properties to faces for the `Nef_polyhedra` objects, and more important, have a way to keep those properties while the object is being transformed. On `Surface_mesh` the [mesh processing corefine algorithms](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/index.html) can use a visitor to define the properties on the transformed mesh based on the source mesh properties. Is there a similar pattern available for `Nef_Polyhedra`?